# Crop and reduce frame rate without loosing quality in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to take my input file (ProRes highest quality 60 fps) and crop it and convert the frame rate to 15 fps. The following did not work (the cropping alone did work, but the frame rate reduction not):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf "crop=1280:1024:320:28" -strict -2 -vcodec prores -profile:v 3 - r 15 -y output.mov
```

I also do not know how ffmpeg exactly converts the frame rates. But what I would like to achieve is that it crops the video and then just takes every 4th frame (60/15) and keep the remaining frames on the same quality (copy the original codec).

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Share the full console output of the command.